# Orthgonality of $\sin(\frac{k\pi x}{L})\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$ over the half period $x\in[0,L]$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, orthogonality

I have been trying to solve a PDE where I encounter the expression

$$
\int_0^L \sin(\frac{k\pi x}{L})\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\mathrm{d}x \tag A
$$

I know that
$$
\int_{-L}^L \sin(\frac{k\pi x}{L})\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{2L} \sin(\frac{k\pi x}{L})\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\mathrm{d}x=0
$$
I have considered the domain to be $x\in [0,L]$ while modelling my problem.

**Is there any series representation or solution to the integral in (A) which I could use ?**

---

**CONTEXT**

Ultimately I would like to solve something like

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {}\int_0^L \sin(\frac{k\pi x}{L})\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) \mathrm{d}x
$$

---

**ATTEMPT**
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^L \sin(\frac{k\pi x}{L})\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) \mathrm{d}x\\ \Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} \Bigg[\frac{L(\cos((k-n)\pi) - 1)}{(k-n)\pi} - \frac{L(\cos((k+n)\pi) + 1)}{(k+n)\pi}\Bigg]
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is not always $0$. Use the formula $\sin A \cos B=\frac  1 2 (\sin (A+B)-\sin (A-B))$ to evaluate the integral.

Comment: I used your suggestion and did the integral. I have added it as an **ATTEMPT** section to the original question. So now I should search for the values of $k$ where the expression results to zero ?